# How to add Thymleaf Snippets to Eclipse IDE?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, thymeleaf

I understand that we could add java templates by 
Window->show view-> Templates

Is there anyway I could add Custom Thymleaf Snippets to it?

Comment: When you open such a file, is the option not there?

Comment: Yes! When open add new template. I don't find an option to add Thymleaf template  on the list of context options.

Comment: @Lucky Got it..Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add code snippets in,

```
Window > Show View > Snippets
```